Use Regulatory Domain data from regulatory.db instead of wifi adapter's EEPROM
I'm using OpenWrt 23.05.05 (i compiled it for my custom system) and have two WiFi chips (QCN9074) that use the ath11k_pci driver. I also have a regulatory.db file located in /lib/firmware.
I want to use this file as the source of regulatory data for the cards instead of their built-in regulatory data. Currently, they are self-managed as shown by
iw reg get

and I want to change this. Is it possible to do so?
